# Restrictions around Protocols and Generics in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

There are scenarios when two interacting sets of generic classes is a good design pattern. A simple example is the Observable-Observer pattern. The observable posts events to the observer but the pattern is the same no matter what type of event that is being observed.

My first thought was that the preferred way would be to define two generic protocols. This should offer the smallest coupling, which tends to be good as the code base grows.

```
protocol ProtocolObserver {
    typealias EventType
    func update<O:ProtocolObservable where O.EventType == EventType>(observable:O, event:EventType) -> Void
}

protocol ProtocolObservable {
    typealias EventType
    func registerObserver<O:ProtocolObserver where O.EventType == EventType>(observer:O) -> Bool
    func unregisterObserver<O:ProtocolObserver where O.EventType == EventType>(observer:O) -> Void
}
```

Trying to define classes that implement the above protocols turned out to be a world of hurt. I failed to find any way to do it.

Implementing a generic baseclass would, however, be an acceptable solution.

```
protocol GenericObserver {
    func update<EventType>(observable:GenericObservable<EventType>, event:EventType);
}

class GenericObservable<EventType> {
    private var observers:[GenericObserver] = []
    func registerObserver(observer:GenericObserver) -> Bool {
        // Code to avoid registering the same observer twice
        observers.append(observer)
        return true
    }
    func unregisterObserver(observer:GenericObserver) -> Void {
        // Code to remove the observer if present in observers
    }
    func notifyObservers(event:EventType) -> Void {
        for observer in observers {
            observer.update(self, event: event)
        }
    }
}
```

No problem defining some classes that implement the protocol this time. Adding them to an instance of the generic observer did not show the behaviour I expected.

```
let numberObservable = GenericObservable<NSNumber>()

class NumberObserver : GenericObserver {
   func update<NSNumber>(observable:GenericObservable<NSNumber>, event:NSNumber) {
       print("Number Event \(event)")
   }
}

let numberObserver = NumberObserver()

numberObservable.registerObserver(numberObserver)

class DataObserver : GenericObserver {
    func update<NSData>(observable:GenericObservable<NSData>, event:NSData) {
        print("Data Event \(event)")
    }
}

let dataObserver = DataObserver()

numberObservable.registerObserver(dataObserver)

numberObservable.notifyObservers(NSNumber(int: 42))
```

I expected `numberObservable.registerObserver(dataObserver)` to cause a compilation error. Instead it happily printed the output

```
Number Event 42
Data Event 42
```

This all leaves me with two questions:

1. What have I misunderstood when I expect the compiler to not accept `numberObservable.registerObserver(dataObserver)`?
2. Is there a way to implement a pair of classes that conform to `ProtocolObserver` and `ProtocolObservable` respectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your questions, 1 and 2, are in fact strongly related.

Before getting started though, I should point out that when you have first-class functions, the observable/observer pattern is almost entirely redundant.  Instead of mandating interfaces for callbacks, you can just supply a closure. I’ll show this in the answer to question 2.

First, 1.  The problem you are experiencing is type erasure. Your base class is the only place in which you have defined `registerObserver` and it looks like this:

```
class GenericObservable<EventType> {
    private var observers:[GenericObserver] = []
    func registerObserver(observer:GenericObserver) -> Bool {
        // Code to avoid registering the same observer twice
        observers.append(observer)
        return true
    }
   //...
}
```

That is, it will take and store a protocol reference to any type. There is no constraint on what that type is, it can be anything.  For example, you could notify an `Int`:

```
extension Int: GenericObserver {
    func update<EventType>(observable:GenericObservable<EventType>, event:EventType) {
        print("Integer \(self)")
    }
}

numberObservable.registerObserver(2)
```

The problem will come when the callees try to use `EventType`. `EventType` could be *anything*. It is similar to this function:

```
func f<T>(t: T) { }
```

`T` can be any type you like – a `String`, an `Int`, a `Foo`. But you will not be able to do anything with it, because it provides zero guarantees. To make a generic type useful, you have to either constrain it (i.e. guarantee it has certain features, like that it’s an `IntegerType` that can be added/subtracted for example), or pass it on to another generic function that similarly unconstrained (such as put it in a generic collection, or call `print` or `unsafeBitCast` which will operate on any type).

Basically, your observers have all declared “I have a family of methods, `update`, which you can call with any type you like”.  This is not very useful, unless you’re writing something like `map` or a generic collection like an array, in which case you don’t care what `T` is.

This might help clear up some confusion – this does *not* do what you think it does:

```
class DataObserver : GenericObserver {
    func update<NSData>(observable:GenericObservable<NSData>, event:NSData) {
        print("Data Event \(event)")
    }
}
```

Here you have *not* declared that `DataObserver` specifically takes an `NSData` class.  You’ve just named the generic placeholder `NSData`.  Similar to naming a variable `NSData` – it doesn’t mean that is what the variable is, just that’s what you’ve called it.  You could have written this:

```
class DataObserver : GenericObserver {
    func update<Bork>(observable:GenericObservable<Bork>, event: Bork) {
        print("Data Event \(event)")
    }
}
```

---

Ok so how to implement an observable protocol with an associated type (i.e. a typealias in the protocol).  Here’s an example of one. But note, there is no `Observer` protocol. Instead, `Observable` will take any function that receives the appropriate event type.

```
protocol Observable {
    typealias EventType
    func register(f: EventType->())
}
// No need for an "Observer" protocol
```

Now, let’s implement this, fixing `EventType` to be an `Int`:

```
struct FiresIntEvents {
    var observers: [Int->()] = []

    // note, this sets the EventType typealias
    // implicitly via the types of the argument
    mutating func register(f: Int->()) {
        observers.append(f)
    }

    func notifyObservers(i: Int) {
        for f in observers {
            f(i)
        }
    }
}

var observable = FiresIntEvents()
```

Now, if we want to observe via a class, we can:

```
class IntReceiverClass {
    func receiveInt(i: Int) {
        print("Class received \(i)")
    }
}

let intReceiver = IntReceiverClass()
// hook up the observing class to observe
observable.register(intReceiver.receiveInt)
```

But we can also register arbitrary functions:

```
observable.register { print("Unowned closure received \($0)") }
```

Or register two different functions on the same receiver:

```
extension IntReceiverClass {
    func recieveIntAgain(i: Int) {
        print("Class recevied \(i) slightly differently")
    }
}

observable.register(intReceiver.recieveIntAgain)
```

Now, when you fire the events:

```
observable.notifyObservers(42)
```

you get the following output:

```
Class received 42
Unowned closure received 42
Class recevied 42 slightly differently
```

But with this technique, if you try to register a function of the wrong event type, you get a compilation error:

```
observable.register(IntReceiverClass.receiveString)
// error: cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(IntReceiverClass -> (String) -> ())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this very interesting and illuminating answer. Yeah old C++ programmer did indeed believe he had introduced two different types in the same way as instantiating a C++ template works. 

Just to clarify one point around my second question. Swift does not allow me to use the `Observable` protocol as variable or function argument. Am I right to say that this makes it impossible to use a pair of protocols like the `ProtocolObserver` and `ProtocolObservable` I used in my example?

Comment: Yeah, no partial specialization is something that trips up C++ devs with Swift. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30483738/3925941) for some more info on the reason you can’t use `ProtocolObserver` as an argument is it has an associated type.

Comment: @Airspeed Can you please explain a little bit, how does `observable.register(intReceiver.receiveInt)` work? I believe that this method accepts a function (strictly saying, a pointer to some memory in a code segment) without any associated data. Am I wrong? How does `observable` capture `intReceiver` to call a method on it later?

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity thanks for the nice implementation of the observable protocol. I want to implement that principle, but, to prevent memory leaks, I need to unregister registered closures. Maybe you can have a look on my question regarding that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800432/closure-identity-in-swift-unregister-observing-closure